# Regex for string *11F23H3*: Start and end with *, 7 Uppercase literals or numbers in between

Tags: regex

I need to check strings like `*11F23H3*` that start and end with a `*`and have 7 uppercase literals or numbers in between. So far I have:

```
if (!barcode.match('[*A-Z0-9*]')) {
  console.error(`ERROR: Barcode not valid`);
  process.exitCode = 1;    
}
```

But this does not cover strings like `*11111111111*`. How would the correct regex look like?

Comment: You can use `/\*[A-Z0-9]{7}\*/`

Comment: Try `'^[*][A-Z0-9]{7}[*]$'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to check strings like *11F23H3* that start and end with a *and have 7 uppercase literals or numbers in between

You can use this regex:

```
/\*[A-Z0-9]{7}\*/
```

- `*` is regex meta character that needs to be escaped outside character class
- `[A-Z0-9]{7}` will match 7 characters containing uppercase letter or digits

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVdGj4/1)

**Code:**

```
var re = /\*[A-Z0-9]{7}\*/;

if (!re.test(barcode)) {
  console.error(`ERROR: Barcode ${barcode} in row ${row} is not valid`);
  process.exitCode = 1;    
}
```

Note that if barcode is only going to have this string then you should also use anchors like this to avoid matching any other text on either side of `*`:

```
var re = /^\*[A-Z0-9]{7}\*$/;
```